# MySQL Join with file_manage table multiple columns

Tags: mysql, json, codeigniter, arraylist

I need to create JSON file using my destination table and file_manage table.
cover image, banner image and galery images id in destination table. gallery ids are serialize

you can downloada database = https://  www.dropbox.com/sh/za4w20fqit27qjg/AACx9T3ArMb_gegAqxRXdUOHa?dl=0

[destination table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eMyZG.jpg)
[file manage table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCSSm.jpg)

Comment: You can Downloada DATABASE  https://www.dropbox.com/s/b2d8g4gqyfj4qn6/holiday-tours.rar?dl=0

Comment: DATABASE name is holiday-tours

Answer (score 0):

You should create a model function like this:

```
function get_json() {
    $q = $this->db->select('cover, banner, gallery')->from('destination');
    $q = $this->db->select('d_id')->from('file_manage');
    $q = $this->db->join('d_id', 'destination.id = file_manage.id', 'left');
    $query = $q->db->get();
    echo json_encode($query->result_array());
    exit;
}
```

[Learn more about codeigniter joins](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html)

Comment: thankx for comment but this not working,  i need fully data array --
$this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('destination');
        $this->db->join('file_manage', 'file_manage.id = destination.cover','left');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        $query->result_array();
this query join only cove id, i need al so  banner, and gallery, gallery ids are serialized

Answer (score 0):

Create destination_model model and something_name_function() method with this:

```
$this->db->select('cover,banner,gallery');
$this->db->join('d_id', 'destination.id = file_manage.id', 'left');
$query = $this->db->get('destination');
return json_encode($query->result_array());
```

load your model in controller and get data

```
$this->load->model('destination_model');
$json = $this->destination_model->something_name_function();
```